# UITabBarController is running parallel with my splashsceen

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios9

I have a `UITabBarController` container 4 view controllers and two other view controllers as `SplashScreenVC` and `LoginScreenVC` as i have set `UINavigationViewController` as root view controller and initiate splash screen with the help of navigation controller in my storyboard but when i actually run the app tabBarController and splash screen both run simultaneously. I want to load all of the views of the tab bar to be load after the splash screen and submission of login details. 
Here is my code where i set root view controller.

```
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
homeVC.title = @"Home";

NotificationViewController *notificationVC = [[NotificationViewController alloc]init];
notificationVC.title = @"Notifications";

ProfileViewController *profileVC = [[ProfileViewController alloc]init];
profileVC.title = @"Profile";

SelfiesCollectionViewController *selfiesCollectionVC = [[SelfiesCollectionViewController alloc]init];
selfiesCollectionVC.title = @"Selfie Collection";

homeVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];

profileVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileViewController"];

notificationVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NotificationViewController"];

selfiesCollectionVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SelfiesCollectionViewController"];



self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
self.tabBarController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UITabBarController"];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[homeVC,notificationVC,profileVC,selfiesCollectionVC];


UINavigationController *navigationVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
navigationVC = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UINavigationController"];


[self.window setRootViewController:navigationVC];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following things.

1)If you are working in Xcode 7 onwards, You have special storyboard for splash screen.  You can set your image in that storyboard.

What do you exactly need tab bar controller or navigation controller?

According to my assumption you need navigation controller for login controller.  If my assumption is true then you have to create navigation controller's object in following way

```
UINavigationController *navigationVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:LoginScreenVC];
```

now you have to add this navigationVc in your tabBarController's viewControllers array. and instead of setting navigationVc as root controller of you window, you can set tab bar as root controller

```
[self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
```

Suggestion:  If you are using storyboard you don't have to write all these lines.  You can do it very easily in your storyboard file by using segues.

Comment: Sit there is still an issue..
According to your solution my loginVC has no become the part of tab bar.
And still the other view controllers of tab bar are still running together.
I want to show the login screen first then check the username and password after confirmation then i want to run my tab bar and view controllers inside the tab bar.
But my problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You should not `alloc` and `init` your `tabBarController` before or the need.
In your you need to make a public method like below.
Remove the allocation and initiation of `tabBarController` from `application launchWithOption` method

```
-(void)userDidLoggedIn{
     self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
self.tabBarController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UITabBarController"];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[homeVC,notificationVC,profileVC,selfiesCollectionVC];
[self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];

}
```

Now simply call this method on the success of login button like this..

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate userDidLoggedIn];
```